# Sufficient conditions for chain recurrent set equal to set of non wandering points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, hyperbolic-dynamics

Given a generic diffeomorphism, I know that the set of nonwandering points is contained in the chain recurrent set, but the converse is not always true. Is there some sufficient conditions under which the equality of the sets hold? I would like to use a $C^1$ Pugh's Closing lemma, but as far as I know from my research, there is no $C^1$  closing lemma for chain recurrence in dimensions greater than 2.